# How do I start a powershell script via relative path and executionpolicy set to bypass?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scripting

I am writing a script for my company to automatically finalize the clients which got set up by MS Sccm. So I need a batch file which starts a PS script via a relative path and executionpolicy set to bypass.

What I had worked for quiet a while, know somehow it doesn't really work anymore:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "script\clientfinalizer.ps1"
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Your question title and body mention a relative path, yet you haven't used one. For a file relative to the current directory, for example, did you try `@"%__APPDIR__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File ".\script\clientfinalizer.ps1"`?

Comment: You don't need specify path for powershell. Just use: powershell -command

Comment: @Compo oh, thanks that worked great ^^ but why did mine not work? Where was the problem? i mean script/clientfinalizer is a relative path, isnt it?

Comment: @Hoshie, not specifying the full path and extension relies of not having potential deliberate, or accidental, modification of modifiable registry and/or environment variables. Safety is better than hoping or guessing, and you do not use `-Command` to run a script, you use `-File`. ItzImmmy, as I stated, you weren't using a relative path, which are prepended similar to these, `.\ `, `..\ `, `..\..\ ` etc. (and please don't use the `Bypass` execution policy)!

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the help! But does the script now run on every pc even though the exectionpolicy is set to remotesigned?

Comment: Please take a look at [what each execution policy means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7). For safety, you should not be executing scripts, for instance downloaded from the intenet.

Comment: It should run on every PC. @Compo I think he understands that it's less secure. If code signing wasn't so complicated (and costly if you want to do it right) I'm sure everyone would do it.